# how to disable generated signed apk android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Hi I tried generated signed apk 1 times for testing and now i only want to stimulate on tested devices but android studio always generated signed apk. That will make the process longer (every time I hit run button android studio will generated signed apk automatically) how to disable auto generated signed apk? i just want to run app on simulator only?

Comment: change the build variant from *release to *debug

Comment: Thanks How to change the build variant?

Answer (score 9):

There is a tab, which is normally at the bottom left corner of AS. Change it from *release to *debug.

[image: Build variant tab]

(Image source : Matt W Ott, [Android TDD with Robolectric and JUnit](http://www.develottment.com/2014/08/android-tdd-with-robolectric-and-junit.html))

Comment: I have checked according to the image. Change to debug already but still auto generate signed apk. Dont know why

Comment: can i see your build.gradle file, the `signingConfigs` part.

Comment: My build.gradle// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Not the top-level build file, i am interested in the second one  : the one specific to your app module.

Comment: perfect answere some whow

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio seems to always do the last build type you did.

So just select Build -> Build APK, and next time it will do this instead of Generate Signed APK.

Answer (score 0):

> When running or debugging your project from the IDE, Android Studio automatically signs your APK with a debug certificate generated by the Android SDK tools. The first time you run or debug your project in Android Studio, the IDE automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate in $HOME/.android/debug.keystore, and sets the keystore and key passwords.

If the build variant is RELEASE, you have to provide the signing config but the apk must be signed becuase:

> Android requires that all APKs be digitally signed with a certificate before they can be installed.

Source: [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

try to this way opens
build.gradle(Module:app)
Then go to
buildTypes {}
and Remove (Delete)

**debug {signingConfig signingConfigs.config}**

then 
Sync Now
and run "app"