# Can't authenticate using the GoogleMapsApi for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

after hours of searching I have to ask this question. I made simple Android app, that is supposed to show a map, get your location and move the camera there.

But I'm having problems with getting the Api to run. I'm getting this message on execution:

```
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
```

I will look over the point that according to the documentation I shouldn't need any authentication for using Maps at all, but to be sure I got my google-services.json file. Android studio for some reason doesn't allow adding files into the apps folder, so I went there with the file browser and added it manually. Still the same error.

I would really appreciate help, because I'm completely stuck. If it's an error with gradle don't be to hard, I haven't used it before. If you need something of my source code or gradle files just tell me.

Comment: Did you try following the answers provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize

Comment: I have all of them tried, except 2nd answer 4th step, becasue i don't know where to put that.

Comment: Are you add ``compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'`` and ``apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`` to Gradle ??

Comment: Yeah, seems like you haven't even added the dependencies to your gradle file, which should have been step number 1. Show us your gradle file.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LpRSFU7J
This is my app level build.gradle

Comment: the `apply plugin:` part has to come after the dependencies, that at least fixed it for me