# GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10 in Google Maps App

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to run the default Google MAps application from Android Studio, I already have the API key. The problem is I am getting this error:

```
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

01-27 18:58:26.980 16757-16757/elbauldelprogramador.com.gpsqr E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.

01-27 18:58:26.990 16757-16788/elbauldelprogramador.com.gpsqr E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

I've checked this answer: [GoogleService failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize/34388626#34388626) and have placed the json in app/, But still does not work.

The thing is The app runs correctly in an Sony Xperia Z1 and a Galaxy S II. But in my Huawei Honor 4x is not working.

Does somebody have any clue of what may be happening?

Comment: Do the phones have the latest Google Play services installed?

Comment: Yes, it is installed

Comment: Is the Huawei Honor 4x using the default ROM (based on [phonearena](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/honor-4X_id9356), its using EMUI)? Some ROMs don't have the necessary google apps and you'll need to install them manually. Did you install the Google Apps manually on the Huawei phone as well? I'm not sure if I'm just repeating the question of @Shmuel as well.

Comment: @adjuremods It has emui and google Services and Maps installed (maps intalled manually via Google Play). The thing is it worked for a while (One execution only) and stopped working again.

Comment: Any help? still now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, what was happening is the SD card was being unmounted when the device was connected over USB. If I launch the app without the usb plugged it works perfectly.