# GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: In Android

Tags: android

Signed APK is getting below Error

> GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

when I run the same code with Dubug.APK it's working fine.

below is build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0' }}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services''
```

Comment: why you don't read your error message carefully. It states that you have to create a string resource `R.string.google_app_id`.

Comment: I have added the same string but getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss to add google-service.json file. As I know you have created your app on google Developer from there you need to download the google-service.json file and put it into your app folder

Step for putting google-service.json to app folder:

```
1) in android studio double tap the shift button and search for terminal 
2) $ mv path-to-download/google-services.json app/ for Ubuntu/MAC OS 
3) For google-service.json use generate file button from this link
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

for more detail please refer below link
[GoogleService failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize)

Comment: let me know if you have any issue

Comment: I am using Mac laptop and android studio. and i have copied google-service.json. But i have doubt whether i copied to right place or not

Comment: do one thing copy it to app folder of your aplication

Comment: if you already copied check it into app folder. if present it means you have copied in right way

Comment: No Anjali . i tried in android studio comment promit its says "Command not found".

$ mv /Users/parvendan/Downloads/google-services.json app/ . 

what is  path-to-download? its path of downloaded google-service.json file?/

Comment: path-to-download is path of google-service.json and dont copy $ sign

Comment: Yeah i gave the same path of google-service.json. but it says comment not found

Comment: Noo. But i copied the file into App. and i have checked file will be present

Comment: then what an issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101994/discussion-between-anjali-tripathi-and-john).