# google_app_id missing and Google services failed to inittialize

Tags: java, android

I've imported a project from my desktop which is already built and runnig. but when try in my computer,it is giving me the below errors.  what does google app id mean? what might be the cause for such type of errors.
thanks in advance.

logcat:

```
02-08 13:14:46.328 23043-23043/ E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
02-08 13:14:46.328 23043-23043/ E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
02-08 13:14:46.358 23043-23073/ E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
02-08 13:14:46.500 23043-23043/E/F: NO ACCOUNT ID
```

Comment: Please refer this link and register the app into google developer console link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize"

Comment: is each json file unique? or how it is application specific?

Answer (score 11):

may be you forgot add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to the bottom of build.gradle.

and you can get more info at https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 2):

If you recently update your Android Studio to 3.3.1 that have a problem with com.google.gms:google-services (Below 4.2.0) dependencies So please update com.google.gms:google-services to 4.2.0

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```