# Setting google_app_id without google_play_services.json or gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

> 02-17 18:16:09.870: E/GMPM(12680): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

I'm trying to remove this error log. I could find some advices about solving this kind of problems using **google_play_services.json** file like this link :
[GoogleService failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize)

But my project doesn't use gradle so I'll add google_app_id in my strings.xml. Now I'm confused. What exactly is google_app_id? Somebody says it's the project number, some says it's the project id... Even in google_play_services.json file there are some properties named "project_id", "project_number", "mobilesdk_app_id", "client_id" and still no "google_app_id" property.

Is it ok with unique value of each apps? If so, it'll be working with project id or number, but I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please see this post, which provides a way to do this using resource files (seen about halfway down the page):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize%22
Simply put the string resource within strings.xml

Comment: @vontell Thank you, but your link is already in my post and I know how to add in resource file. I just want to know which info should I input in google_app_id string.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, **juste remove "google_app_id" from your string.xml** file (it will avoid duplicate)