# Difference between "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location" and "com.google.android.gms:play-services"

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to understand the reason for an error. Here is what I did:

- Start Android Studio
- Start a new project with a Blank Activity
- Add the line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` to the dependencies section of the app module `build.gradle`

That's it. If I now run this app, it gives me the the following error in logcat:

```
03-01 14:28:58.646 3133-3133/local.abc.t2 E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
03-01 14:28:58.646 3133-3133/local.abc.t2 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
03-01 14:28:58.756 3133-3191/local.abc.t2 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

However, if I replace `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` by `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0`, the error is no longer present.

I know that the `play-services` version includes multiple Google Play service APIs and `play-services-location` includes only the location APIs. So, at least one of the other APIs is causing the above error. Which one is causing which error and how can I find out?

Comment: This is strange, you should not need to use the google-services.json unless you're doing GCM stuff.  Maybe check your gradle configuration.  Regardless, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the "Maps" API, which requires a key created from [Google Developer's Console](http://console.developers.google.com).

Most other APIs require a key as well

Comment: No, that would not be a problem, unless you were trying to show a map without an API key.