# GoogleService failed to initialize - Google Services for an existing app with multiple Google API projects

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Since I updated the Play Services in my app to 8.4.0:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

I get the following message in the debugger:

> GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected
>   resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. 
>   Possible causes are missing google-services.json or
>   com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize) I can either create JSON file and add it to my project or add

```
<string name="google_app_id">YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER</string>
```

to the values resource file.

My problem is though that I have multiple Google API projects created for my app- one for Maps, another for GCM, and a third for in-app purchases.

Which project number should I use to set the google_app_id with? Can I specify multiple "google_app_id"s?

Comment: The answer is not to specify multiple JSON files (multiple projects), rather user one project and add all necessary APIs for the application to it.