# Airpush app integration not working properly

Tags: android, ads, airpush

Hi I am using Airpush in my app according to this [official link](http://docs.airpush.com/index.php/Universal_SDK_8.13). But I am showing only Banner ads. Nothing more. I have integrated SmartWall, Notification Ads and Icon Ads. But I don't get them. Here is my logcat

> 04-07 08:10:36.761 3477-3477/bengal.golden.com.airpush E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzaq
>   04-07 08:10:36.761 3477-3477/bengal.golden.com.airpush E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzb
>   04-07 08:10:37.011 3477-3477/bengal.golden.com.airpush E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
>   04-07 08:10:37.011 3477-3477/bengal.golden.com.airpush E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
>   04-07 08:10:37.091 3477-3511/bengal.golden.com.airpush E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
>   04-07 08:15:38.055 3477-3477/bengal.golden.com.airpush E/USDK: Error occurred while showing Cache ad: SmartWall ad is not available in cache

**NB: Log Level - Error Only**

Please help. Or if you can show me or give me a link which give me a detailed tutorial of Airpush SDK 8.13 integration, I will be so pleased...

Comment: did you add google play services to your project in your

Comment: Yes. I added `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

Comment: Check this link  you are missing Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize

Comment: check this it may help you. http://androidadvertise.blogspot.in/p/how-to-implement-airpush-in-android.html         http://www.androidtrainee.com/how-to-implement-airpush-ads-in-android-application/