# Google Analytics works on desktop but not on Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to implement Google Analytics to my app. I can see hits when trying on Unity editor and also see real time users in analytics dashboard. However when I build my game on device I cannot see users on real time. I wait for a day no data has been sent from device.

```
    try {

        googleAnalytics.LogScreen(new AppViewHitBuilder()
            .SetScreenName("Main Menu"));;

        debuggerText.text = "Succes";
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        debuggerText.text = ex.ToString();

    }
```

This return success both on desktop and device but on device no data sent. 
I search all similar questions but nothing helps ? 
Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: Where can I check the logs when building on device ? On desktop in console it show succesfully sent hits to google analytics.

Comment: do your homework http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html, check the logs on your Android device the moment you are sending the log

Comment: find the logs. Here 04-15 16:02:09.657: E/GMPM(12430): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find the logs. Here 04-15 16:02:09.657: E/GMPM(12430): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Now when you have read the logs you have to fix the cause: Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id'

Here is [GoogleService failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize) the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have a **white-space** or **new line** in your tracking code.

I suggest you first delete your current tracking code from Unity. Now, **copy** your tracking code from Google/web to **notepad** then copy it directly from **notepad** to **Unity**. This will make sure that you don't have **white-space** or **new line** in your tracking code while copying it from the web.

Comment: I make changes on GAv4 prefab wrote the tracking code myself no copy paste. Nothing changes.