# Android app crashing on Google Maps Activity

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2, android-maps

It is showing the error message that the app is unfortunately closed when I move from the **AddReminder Activity** to the **AddEventPlace Activity**.

**DataBaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String tbl_User = "User";
    String tbl_Reminder = "Reminder";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Remind_Me.db";
    public static final String COL_1 = "Username";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Password";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Email";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Contact_No";

    public static final String COL_5 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_6 = "item";
    public static final String COL_7 = "time";
    public static final String COL_8 = "date";
    public static final String COL_9 = "x_coordinates";
    public static final String COL_10 = "y_coordinates";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table  if not exists User  (Username TEXT PRIMARY KEY ,Password TEXT, Email TEXT, Contact_No INTEGER)");

        db.execSQL("create table Reminder (ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  ," +
                "item TEXT," +
                " Time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," +
                "Date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," +
                " x_coordinates REAL," +
                "y_coordinates  REAL," +
                "FOREIGN KEY(Username) REFERENCES User(USERNAME) )");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Reminder");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertUser(String Username, String password, String Email, int ContactNO) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, Username);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, password);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, Email);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, ContactNO);
        long result = db.insert(tbl_User, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean AddReminder(String item, double x_coordinates, double y_coordinates, String Username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_6, item);
        contentValues.put(COL_7, " time('now') ");
        contentValues.put(COL_8, java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());
        contentValues.put(COL_9, x_coordinates);
        contentValues.put(COL_10, y_coordinates);
        contentValues.put(COL_1, Username);
        long result = db.insert(tbl_Reminder, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

**AddReminder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.champ.remindme2.AddReminder">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:src="@drawable/remind_me_logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtitem"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/plusButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/plusButton"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edited_text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plusButton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NextButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NextButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_botton"
        android:onClick="plus"
        android:text="+" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NextButton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BackButton"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_botton"
        android:onClick="AddEventPlace"
        android:text="Next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BackButton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtitem"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtitem"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_botton"
        android:onClick="Back"
        android:text="Back" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AddReminder.java**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Address"
            android:layout_width="183dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.98" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bsearch"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onSearch"
            android:text="Search" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="382dp"
            android:layout_height="383dp"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDone"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="Done"
        android:text="Done" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AddEventplace.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Address"
            android:layout_width="183dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.98" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bsearch"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onSearch"
            android:text="Search" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="382dp"
            android:layout_height="383dp"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDone"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="Done"
        android:text="Done" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AddEventPlace.java**

```
public class AddEventPlace extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    DatabaseHelper Db;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    double Latitude;
    double Longitude;
    Button btnDone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_event_place);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }


    public void onSearch(View view) {
        EditText location_tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Address);
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;
        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            Latitude = address.getLatitude();
            Longitude = address.getLongitude();
            Latitude = 0.0;
            Longitude = 0.0;
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        }
    }

    public void Done(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        String Username = intent.getExtras().getString("Username");
        String item = intent.getExtras().getString("item");
        boolean isInserted = Db.AddReminder(item, Latitude, Longitude, Username);
        if (isInserted == true) {
            Toast.makeText(AddEventPlace.this, "Reminder is added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            intent.putExtra("Username", Username);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(AddEventPlace.this, "Reminder is not added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
05-12 11:54:20.249 2427-2427/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10055: Read-only file system
05-12 11:54:20.311 2427-2435/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
05-12 11:54:26.297 2427-2427/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
05-12 11:54:26.298 2427-2427/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
05-12 11:54:26.578 2427-2518/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
05-12 11:55:34.762 2427-2427/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.champ.remindme2, PID: 2427
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.champ.remindme2.AddEventPlace.Done(AddEventPlace.java:107)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
05-12 11:59:59.915 6972-6972/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
05-12 11:59:59.917 6972-6972/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
05-12 12:00:00.082 6972-7001/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
05-12 12:01:46.745 6972-6972/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.champ.remindme2, PID: 6972
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Back(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'BackButton'
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:321)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:280)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-12 12:01:51.682 8463-8463/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
05-12 12:01:51.683 8463-8463/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
05-12 12:01:51.989 8463-8500/com.example.champ.remindme2 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

Comment: add error log so we can see error cause.

Comment: i have updated the post check.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

> Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for
>   initializing Google services.

You need to add `google_app_id` to your resources like this:

```
<string name="google_app_id">PROJECT_NUMBER</string>
```

You can generate your project number from the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As logcat suggest you have not setup google service properly.

> Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for
>   initializing Google services. Possible causes are missing
>   google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services

Add `<string name="google_app_id">id of project</string>` in string.xml file and get google-services.json from google developer console and put in root folder of your app code (in \app folder).

and in manifest file add this line

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_api_key" />
```

Comment: Project_NUMBER means?

Answer (score 0):

I saw many problems in your log. so First of all trys to resolve this one first :

***Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.***

by checking this link:

[To solve the first problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize)

then post the new log after.