# GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google Maps in my android application. I have created the key and added necessary permissions in manifest file:

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com..."
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="com....MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**google-maps-api.xml:**

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
    AIzaSyAjGQ-...
</string>
```

Also, I have added the following depedency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` to compile, which is working:

**app.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

I have also added `google-services.json` to **PROJECT_NAME/app/**:

[image]

But when the app is started, I get this message in debugger:

```
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
```

I have followed steps on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize), but regarding my case, what could I miss to configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

1. you should add the plugin to the bottom of your app-level `build.gradle`:

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

2. Add the dependency to your project-level `build.gradle`:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

For more information [Check this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project)

### Edited:

New `build.gradle` looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com..."
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Ok, but where exactly in the that gradle file ? Project or Module ? And where in the code ?

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in what section ? Between what parentheses ?

Comment: @Kapparino check this link in my answer and do as the step say. add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in just below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: I don't understand where this goes `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, on the what line in the file, between what parentheses: android { defaultConfig, buildType {} }  ?

Comment: Omg I have found it. Under `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: With this updates, I'm getting `Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.` So I should use 8.3.0 or 8.4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. i tried to solve it.but no luck.if you have backup project use that one.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. You need to place the configuration file generated by this [Link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In).
> 2. Then you need to Get Configuration file From [This](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start?hl=en) and Download it file named `google.json`.
> 3. Then you need to put that file into your project at app/ or mobile/ directory of your `Android`.
>
> And as you need to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` exact below of `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` as in MD's answer `Build.Gradle` file.

**After that `Build->Clean` your project.**

> And make sure you have string resource available with API_KEY in it named `<string name="google_maps_key">Your Api Key</string>`.