# Google Service failed to initialize, status: 10

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gradle

I'm currently using Google Maps on a app that I'm developing and suddenly my app started to throw an error when I run the app on my phone.

> 10-22 22:19:41.921 26626-26626/? E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

I have seen similar post regarding this issue and I've tried most of those solutions. The majority suggest to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of the `app.gradle` along with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` on my apps gradle.

I' also have the `google-services.json` added on the path `app/`

None of these solutions have worked, does anyone has another workaround?

These are my current gradles

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to              all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'




    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
 }

 allprojects {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
  }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

App specific gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.josebernhardt.rpvc_"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
 }

   dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please [**ensure that your device have the Google Play Services APK**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk).

> As described in the [Google Play services overview](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview), Google Play delivers service updates for users on Android 2.3 and higher through the Google Play Store app. However, updates might not reach all users immediately, so **your app should verify the version available before attempting to perform API transactions.**

And as noted in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk),

> **Note:** Because it is hard to anticipate the state of each device, **you must always check for a compatible Google Play services APK before you access Google Play services features.**

Furthermore, you may want to also try suggested solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize) wherein updating from `play-services:8.4.0` to `play-services:9.2.0` fixed the issue.

Hope that helps!